# U3D-How to enable System.Data in mono on Mac?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, mono

I want to use System.Data in my scripts.
I've referred [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/379212/how-to-solve-the-error-type-or-namespace-systemdat.html).
But I'm still confused. 
Under the ../2.0 directory exists many files.
Does it mean I should copy the .dll file to my plugin folder?
So where is the plugin folder?

I'm new to U3D and my unity version is 5.3.1 personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Plugin folder" refers to the folder inside your project. You need to create a folder called "Plugins" within your "Assets" folder ([source](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder#.22Plugins.2Fx86_64.22)), and in your case, you just need to copy the assembly file `System.Data.dll` (or .so when you're on Mac probably) inside that "Plugins" folder.